# Combining Gridviews with sqldatasources

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, sqldatasource

Good afternoon. I have three gridviews that contain sqldatasource. Both grids are 5x2. What I am trying to figure out is how to combine the multiple gridviews into a table. To get that result, whenever I select an item from a dropdown list, which also has a sqldatasource, it will show the table of the combined three gridviews. 
I attempted to code it, but there was absolutely no result.

```
 Imports System.Data
 Imports System.Data.SqlClient
 Imports System.Configuration

Partial Class companydropdown
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub OnDataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim Gridview1 As New DataTable
    Dim GridView2 As New DataTable
    Dim GridView3 As New DataTable



    Dim primaryKey(0) As DataColumn
    Gridview1.PrimaryKey = {Gridview1.Columns("CompanyID")}
    GridView2.PrimaryKey = {GridView2.Columns("MemberTypeID")}
    GridView3.PrimaryKey = {GridView3.Columns("ReportNameID")}

    Gridview1.Merge(GridView2, False, MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey)
    GridView2.Merge(GridView3, False, MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey)

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Merge-GridView-Cells-or-Columns-in-a-Row-in-ASPNet-using-C-VBNet.aspx

Comment: Gridviews 1,2, & 3 are all local variables.  Nothing exits that `OnDataBound` event.  And also from a programming standpoint you merge 1 with 2 before you merge 2 with 3 so 1 contains 1 & 2 and then 2 contains 2 & 3 - and then they all die

Comment: Also - you never even populate the locally declared DataTables

Comment: Thanks you guys. I'm going to practice it now.